# Problem with forward step in pytorch model

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory

Traceback saying that:

```
* Epoch 1/20
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-4f0f868c6227> in <module>()
      1 max_epochs = 20
      2 optim = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
----> 3 train(model, optim, bce_loss, max_epochs, data_tr, data_val)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    725             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    726         else:
--> 727             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    728         for hook in itertools.chain(
    729                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

TypeError: forward() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

But in train section of my net I did not pass more than two arguments(including self argument)
this is [link to my code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1vkezX_0N-Jw5XVz7gFINXw2lMixBzg4M?usp=sharing)

Maybe problem not in train

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model has sub-modules for which you (implicitly) call `forward` with more than one argument:

```py
x = self.dec_conv3(self.unpool3(x, indices3))
```

Your `unpool` are simply `MaxPool` layers - they do not expect two input arguments.